2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #4 on Salesforce has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Thanks for the warm welcome! I look forward to this opportunity to serve an even greater role in the community. I'd like to thank everyone for their overwhelming support.

Congratulations Brian! Excited for this community!! We are lucky to have you as moderator and cannot wait to see everything that you will bring to the community..

I can't just click on "This answer is useful", but have to make this explicit from my side too: Congratulations! I think I'm not alone to say that when you were entering the candidate list, it looked somewhat inevitable: At least in my area of interest, there's hardly any person (on StackExchange and beyond) I owe as much Salesforce knowledge as you - and not just due to your surprising knowledge and intelligence, but also your willingness to help and always stay constructive. I'm sure you'll do an excellent job, but have fun too!

Congratulations mate - well deserved! Sorry I'm late to the party, been offline more than usual over the last few days for family reasons

Congrats! Definitely well earned.

Congratulations @sfdcfox !!

Congratulations @sfdcfox, well deserved!
